# How do I mock data for the subscriber

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running a unit test on angular app, I want to pass on data to subscribe as shown in the code below, I tried many ways let me know which one is correct

```
getData() {

    this.http.post<Transactions[]>('/api/getrecords', this.filter)
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res['status'] == "FAILURE") {

      //do something
      } else {
        console.log(res['status']);
        this.data = res['data'];
        }
}
```

tried to pass on getData like this

```
 mockService.getData=of(mockUsageRecords);//tried this
 mockService.getData=mockUsageRecords;//tried this
 mockService.getData.and.returnValue(of(mockUsageRecords));//this one gives error
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire code of the test-file, as well as the error output? This seems to be fairly easy to solve then.

Comment: You also should [mark answers people give you as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when they are, and upvote them as well if they are helpful.  You've asked 13 questions in as many days and haven't marked a single answer as correct ... that de-motivates people to want to help you.